# How to get a specific value from url in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

i am trying to get a value of "token" from this url

token=EC-6HV41821M6960550G

```
url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6HV41821M6960550G"
```

i know it can be done by regex but i think it can be done by some URI method.

Comment: i was trying to make it bold :-) removed it

Comment: Look into the `URI` class. You can't do it in a single step. You have to combine a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do can get it like this:

```
require 'uri'

url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxx"

uri    = URI.parse(url)
params = CGI::parse(uri.query)

params['token'] # => 'EC-xxx'
```

Comment: Thanx it really worked!! you saved me from lot of regex..

Answer (score 2):

Just to show, some other ways also exist :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'uri'

url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxx"
uri = URI(url)
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h['token']
# => "EC-xxx"
```

Read the method [`::decode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form) docomentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'cgi'

url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6HV41821M6960550G'

CGI.parse(url)['token']
```

Comment: +1 for short version...

Comment: -1 is does only work for the `token` parameter, but would fail for `cmd`.

Comment: yes, because `CGI.parse` work just with query, and parse it like split by `&` and then by `=`, so instead of `cmd` parameter you will have `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd`